# Need to start loop *ngFor from given array index

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

**Ionic gallery album**

I can able to view all the images in grid format,if i select one among them,i need to start the ionic slide image from that..

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<ion-slides zoom="true">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of images.imageUrl>
      <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
        <img style="max-width: 95%;" [src]="img.url" (click)="downloadicon()"/>
      </div>
      <span class="icon-save notify" *ngIf="showimage" (click)="downloadImage(img.url,img.public_id)"></span>
    </ion-slide> 
  </ion-slides>
```

**NOTE:**

images.imageUrl - array which contain all images

Comment: Use Slice pipe. https://angular.io/api/common/SlicePipe

Answer (score 1):

You can call goToSlide() on your click event-

```
class MyPage {
  @ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;

  goToSlide() {
    this.slides.slideTo(2, 500);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say that there are 2 options

1. simply you need make another array when user selects one.
   and just use the array in template.
2. when user selects one, save the index number. and add condition in ngFor like below :

I hope this would be helpfule

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let img of images.imageUrl | slice:index ">
```

or

```
<ion-slide *ngFor="let img of images.imageUrl;let row = index">
        <div *ngIf="row > selectedIndex">
            ...
        </div>
    </ion-slide>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..i don't want to slice a array...i just want to start with given array index example: if the index is 2,i can able to swipe right and see further images. that's fine.. but if i swipe to left i need to view index 0,1 images

Answer (score 0):

> Need to start loop *ngFor from given array index

```
<ion-slides zoom="true">
        <ion-slide *ngFor="let img of images.imageUrl | slice:index ">
          <div class="swiper-zoom-container">
            <img style="max-width: 95%;" [src]="img.url" (click)="downloadicon()"/>
          </div>
          <span class="icon-save notify" *ngIf="showimage" (click)="downloadImage(img.url,img.public_id)"></span>
        </ion-slide> 
      </ion-slides>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response..i don't  want to slice a array...i just want to start with given array index
example: if the index is 2,i can able to swipe right and see further images. that's fine..
but if i swipe to left i need to view index 0,1 images